# LineType e shape em ggplot2 no R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou usando o seguinte código para plotar 3 funções:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 2)), aes(x)) +
    stat_function(fun = exp, geom = "line")+
    stat_function(fun = dnorm ,geom = "line")+
    stat_function(fun = cos, colour = "blue")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que que a forma das linhas que desenham as 3 funções acima, fosse dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, a primeira função fosse pontilhada com triângulo, a segunda com asteriscos e a terceira com pontos. As formas (triangulo, asteriscos e pontos) podem ser qualquer uma (quadrado, círculo ...) . Como eu faço para adicionar uma legenda com as respectivas formas para cada linha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar vou criar um vetor com os valores de `x` nos quais eu quero que os pontos sejam plotados. No caso, quero todos os pontos entre 0 e 2, com espaçamento de 0.25:

```
x <- seq(0, 2, by=0.25)
```

Com este vetor eu vou criar um data frame com `x` e os valores das funções que me interessam:

```
dados <- data.frame(x,
                    exp=exp(x),
                    dnorm=dnorm(x),
                    cos=cos(x))
```

Por fim, ploto tudo utilizando um `geom_point` para cada conjunto de pontos da função e um `stat_function` para cada função. Note que cada `geom_point` tem uma `shape` atribuída a ele. Além disso, atribuí parâmetros de `colour` iguais para `geom_point` e `stat_function`.

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x=x, y=exp)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour="exp"), shape=1) +
  stat_function(fun = exp, geom = "line", aes(colour="exp")) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=dnorm, colour="dnorm"), shape=2) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, geom = "line", aes(colour="dnorm")) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=cos, colour="cos"), shape=4) +
  stat_function(fun = cos, geom = "line", aes(colour="cos")) + 
  labs(x="Eixo X", y="f(x)", colour="Legenda")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba também que não defini as cores das linhas e dos pontos como vermelha, azul e verde. Preferi chamá-las de `exp`, `dnorm` e `cos`. Como é super fácil utilizar paletas de cores no `ggplot2`, é melhor definir as cores desta forma, pois a legenda fica mais intuitiva e fica trivial mudar as cores através do comando `scale_color_brewer`.

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x=x, y=exp)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour="exp"), shape=1) +
  stat_function(fun = exp, geom = "line", aes(colour="exp")) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=dnorm, colour="dnorm"), shape=2) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, geom = "line", aes(colour="dnorm")) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=cos, colour="cos"), shape=4) +
  stat_function(fun = cos, geom = "line", aes(colour="cos")) + 
  labs(x="Eixo X", y="f(x)", colour="Legenda") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Perfeito! Vlw!!!